# Postgres Unique JSON Array Aggregate Values

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table that stores values like this:

```
| id | thing | values |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | a     |[1, 2]  |
| 2  | b     |[2, 3]  |
| 3  | a     |[2, 3]  |
```

And would like to use an aggregate function to group by `thing` but store only the unique values of the array such that the result would be:

```
| thing | values  |
|-------|---------|
| a     |[1, 2, 3]|
| b     |[2, 3]   |
```

Is there a simple and performant way of doing this in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you take the JSON array apart with `json_array_elements()` - this is a set-returning function with a `JOIN LATERAL` you get a row with `id`, `thing` and a JSON array element for each element.

Then you select `DISTINCT` records for `thing` and `value`, ordered by `value`.

Finally you aggregate records back together with `json_agg()`.

In SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT thing, json_agg(value) AS values
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT thing, value
    FROM t
    JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(t.values) AS v(value) ON true
    ORDER BY value) x
GROUP BY thing
```

In general you would want to use the `jsonb` type as that is more efficient than `json`. Then you'd have to use the corresponding `jsonb_...()` functions.